# How to identify a software development framework?

Tags: development-process, frameworks

Based on what information, can we identify something as a software development framework? For example the [Wikipedia article of 'software framework'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) claims it should include support programs, compilers, code libraries, etc. But there are some companies I know of which call a code library 'framework'!

What should a certain development environment contain to be considered as a 'framework'?

Comment: The question is too vague. The wikipedia article precisely describes what a framework is, and how it differs from libraries.

Comment: @arnaud: well, the Wikipedia article is not clear enough and lacks examples. The answer by Jörg W Mittag is much more illustrative.

Comment: a doubt is know as **doubt** always... thanks for asking this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing that distinguishes a framework from a library is *inversion of control*: *you* call a library, but you don't call a framework – a framework calls you.

Or to put it another way: when you write an application using a library, you write the application and leave "holes" in it for the boring details which you then "fill" using a library. (Such a boring detail might be "how to sort a list"; you won't write code for that, you'll just call the library's `sort` routine.)

When you write an application using a *framework*, the framework already provides the application for you and just leaves holes in it for the *interesting* details which you then have to fill out.

Comment: +1. But what about the following case: you call a method which does some complicated computing over some data, and sends the results to you in a bunch of events; once received, you post-process and display this data in a specific way. Is this a library or a framework, given that both computing and post-processing are *interesting*?